# Error in moving file in php

Tags: php

I have following script which is showing me warning on `move_uploaded_file`.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/oxfordmo/public_html/ticket/attachement/1320610829.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/oxfordmo/public_html/ticket/open.php on line 53
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpLHjtMJ' to '/home/oxfordmo/public_html/ticket/attachement/1320610829.docx' in /home/oxfordmo/public_html/ticket/open.php on line 53

```
 if ( $file != "" ) {
     $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
     $ext  = pathinfo( $_FILES["file"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
     if ( $ext != "doc" || $ext != "pdf" || $ext != "docx" ) {
         if ( $_FILES["file"]["size"] <= 1024 * 1024 ) {
             if ( file_exists( "$root/ticket/attachement/$time.$ext" ) ) {
                 unlink( "$root/ticket/attachement/$time.$ext" );
             } elseif ( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], "$root/ticket/attachement/$time.$ext" ) ) {
                 $errorfile = "Unable to move file to destination folder.";
             }
             $file = $time . '.' . $ext;
             $query = mysql_query( "UPDATE tkt_container SET attachment='" . $file . "' WHERE ticket_id='" . $ticket_id . "'" ) or die( mysql_error() );
         } else {
             $errorfile = "File not saved. Size limit Exceed! ";
         }
     } else {
         $errorfile = "File not saved. Invalid Format!";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change this line :

```
         } elseif ( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], "$root/ticket/attachement/$time.$ext" ) ) {
```

to

```
         } elseif ( !file_exists($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']) || !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], "$root/ticket/attachement/$time.$ext" ) ) {
```

in that way you will check if the file actually exists before you move it

a good practice is to check the 'error' value in FILES before operate on the uploaded files

Comment: also, after the `$errorfile = "Unable to move file to destination folder.";` statement, the following `$file=..` & `$query=..` are still executed even if there's an error.. should wrap those in an else statement

Comment: the best would be to check the error variable, or at least to add the `file_exists($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'])` to `if($file!="")`